# cpp file #include causing errors, @class not

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, include

In an iPad app im using a thirdParty cpp file that acts as a controller for some UI functionality; its wired up with IB and a `@class` definition is all i need.

However now I'm trying to set a delegate on the cpp file and therefore have to include it in the implementation of my `viewController`.

including the cpp header in my implementation causes a stack of errors to appear much like this:

> [cpp_header_file_path] error: expected
>   '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before '[cpp class]'

and even operators like this:

> [cpp_header_file_path] error: expected
>   '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
>   '**attribute**' before '<' token

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the suffix of your files from .m (Objective-C) to .mm (Objective-C++).